# Firefox next tab is Ctrl+arrow

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Firefox changes my current tab when I press Ctrl+Arrow, when I want it to go the the previous/next word. How can I change this? I would prefer not to use any addons (except Customize Shortcuts, which doesn't have the option.).

I'm using Kubuntu 12.10, if that helps.

Comment: under preferences / advance / acceptability, there is a setting called "always use cursor keys for navigation" is this checked?

Comment: That is not the feature I want (I find that very irritating in fact). I want to move back.front one word when I'm in a text box/URL bar. Nevertheless, enabling that feature didn't change anything

Comment: oh i was just wondering if it was enabled so you could disable it..

Comment: ctrl + arrow does nothing on my firefox (arch linux 64bit + kde)

Comment: it is not a default behavior of firefox as far as I know . There is a possibilty an addon has implemented this shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an add-on called "Sailor Shortcuts" that used Ctrl to shift between tabs. Thanks to @adithya!